# Gmail contact folder disappeared

Tags: gmail, contacts

The contact folder in my Gmail disappeared, both on iPhone and iPad. How do I get it back?

Comment: Are you talking about the Gmail web client or the Gmail account you created in the native Mail.app?

Answer (score 2):

can you post a screen shot? Ideally it should appear in the dropdown menu of the Gmail text on the top left about 1.2 inches from the top, next to it a small downward arrow, click on the arrow, contact should be the 2nd choice

[image]

Answer (score 2):

1. Login to Gmail.
2. In the upper-right corner, click the gear and select “Settings“.
3. Select the “Labels” tab.
4. Select the “Show” or “Hide” link next to the folder you wish to show or hide. In this example, I am …
   System labels   Show in label list
   Inbox                 Show in IMAP

Starred show hide             Show in IMAP

Snoozed show hide             Show in IMAP

Important   show hide             Show in IMAP

Chats   show hide             Show in IMAP

Sent    show hide             Show in IMAP

Drafts  show hide show if unread              Show in IMAP

All Mail    show hide             Show in IMAP

Spam    show hide show if unread              Show in IMAP

Trash   show hide